# Нужна помощь с рандомизацией выбора членов массива

Tags: c++

Есть двумерный массив. В нем записаны некоторые значения и вероятность в процентах на их "выпадение". Как реализовать функцию, которая будет выбирать число из массива с вероятностью, указанной в нем?

Comment: не хватает информации. Как выбирается вероятность из 2 измерения массива?

Comment: К примеру, arr [0][0] - значение, а arr[0][1] - вероятность его выпадения.

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Есть у вас arr[7][42], у меня выпало 7. Откуда мне брать 42, чтобы получать элемент массива?

Comment: Циркулярка. Нужно узнать вероятность выбранного элемента, который выбирается рандомно с вероятностью, которую нужно узнать?

Comment: @АндрейЛобанович Наверное имелось ввиду не двумерный массив а одномерный где `p[n]` это вероятность выпадения числа `n`. Может есть полное условие точное задачи?

Comment: @АндрейЛобанович В целом задача на выпадения чисел с заданной вероятностью считается очень просто. Нужно вначале посчитать массив с кумулятивной вероятностью т.е. `p_cumul[i] = p[i] + p_cumul[i - 1]`, потом нужно просто выбрасывать рандомное число вещественное `px` из отрезка `[0;p_cumul[last]]` и находить такое `i` что `p_cumul[i] <= px < p_cumul[i+1]` и это `i` будет ответом, искомым числом.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul идея такова, что в каждой строке этого массива по 2  значения (число и вероятность его выпадения), а строк любое количество.

Comment: @АндрейЛобанович Тогда понятно как это решать, я описал выше в комментарии, если нужно более подробно с примером тогда я могу оформить в виде ответа полного.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, если не затруднит)

Comment: @АндрейЛобанович Всё, запостил ответ с полным текстом решения на C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот моё решение. Только я вместо двумерного массива сделал массив пар, так вроде проще и наглядней, массив входной `c_probs` содержит пары где первое значение это выбрасываемое число, второй это его вероятность, вероятности могут быть не нормализованные т.е. в сумме давать не ровно 1. Решение заключается просто в вычислении массива распределения, или проще говоря кумулятивной вероятности, т.е. `c_distr[i + 1] = c_probs[i].second + c_distr[i]`. Далее просто рандомно выбрасывается вероятность `prob` из отрезка `[0, c_distr[last]]` и бинарным поиском (для простоты используется std::upper_bound) находится индекс `i` для которого `c_distr[i - 1] <= prob < c_distr[i]`, в итоге результирующее число выброшенное будет `c_probs[i - 1].first`.

Вот текст программы на C++, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow743631var1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

enum {
    c_num_tests = 50,
};

int main() {
    // Значение вероятностей чисел.
    vector< pair<double, double> > const c_probs = {{5.5, 0.1}, {7.1, 0.3}, {1.3, 0.05},};

    // Массив кумулятивных вероятностей или попросту распределение.
    vector<double> c_distr(c_probs.size() + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c_distr.size() - 1; ++i) c_distr[i + 1] = c_probs[i].second + c_distr[i];

    // Стандартный генератор чисел.    
    std::random_device r_dev;
    std::default_random_engine engine(r_dev());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, c_distr.back());
    auto rng = std::bind(distribution, engine);

    // Генерируем точечные значения вероятности и определяем в какой индекс c_distr они попали.
    for (size_t i_test = 0; i_test < c_num_tests; ++i_test) {
        double prob = rng();
        // Просто находит такой индекс i, что c_distr[i - 1] <= prob < c_distr[i].
        int i = std::upper_bound(c_distr.begin(), c_distr.end(), prob) - c_distr.begin();
        // Выводим просто число с индексом i - 1.
        cout << c_probs[i - 1].first << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Как предложил Vladimir Gamalyan, можно использовать уже готовый класс `std::discrete_distribution`, он как раз делает то что я делал вручную выше, вот с ним более простое решение, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow743631var2):

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

enum {
    c_num_tests = 50,
};

int main() {
    // Значение вероятностей чисел.
    vector< pair<double, double> > const c_probs = {{5.5, 0.1}, {7.1, 0.3}, {1.3, 0.05},};

    // Сохраняем только веса.
    vector<double> c_weights(c_probs.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c_probs.size(); ++i) c_weights[i] = c_probs[i].second;

    // Стандартный генератор чисел.    
    std::random_device r_dev;
    std::default_random_engine engine(r_dev());
    std::discrete_distribution<size_t> distribution(c_weights.begin(), c_weights.end());
    auto rng = std::bind(distribution, engine);

    // Генерируем числа с заданными весами.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c_num_tests; ++i) {
        cout << c_probs[rng()].first << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно также использовать [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution), чтобы не писать выборку самому.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Очень хорошее предложение, я даже не знал что есть `discrete_distribution`, она в самый раз подходит, я по сути просто её аналог вручную и реализовал.